# HP 620 Notebook makes noise when run on battery

Tags: 12.04, laptop, battery

This is seems strange but it's true when i use my Hp Notebook 620 on battery it makes strange noise , I cant describe it exactly but it sounds like a clock ticking every 5 or 10 second ( maybe more) and I can't find the source of it but it's not the cpu fan nor the harddisk or   the speakers for sure.. also am running dual OS and there's no noise with win7 but if I plug the charger it stops ... any idea please ??

OS ubuntu 12.04 32bit

Comment: Without hearing it or at least having a good description of what it sounds like, it is impossible to say.

Comment: thanks for replying , well I cant describe it exactly but it sounds like a clock ticking every 5 or 10 second maybe more and I can't find the source of it but it's not the cpu fan for sure.. also am runnig dual os and there's no noise with  win7

Comment: I recommend adding that description to the question. If possible, please record the noise, post in on the web somewhere, and add a link to it. Have you tried muting sound, to make sure the noise isn't simply coming from the speaker (and thus created by some application or by a problem with sound drivers)?

Comment: thanks again for the suggestions  I will try to record it even it's not  very load also I am a ubuntu noob this is is first time using this os so i have installed just few application like conky,ktorrent,vlc, and after i discoverd th problem i installed an application called jupiter it didnt work

Answer (score 1):

It could be a phenomenon called CPU-Whining.
It is noise from the CPU voltage regulators when the CPU changes to different speeds.

Comment: Can you provide more information, or add a link to an article/post somewhere about this topic?